# Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle: How does this uncertainty compare to the energy of the transition?

Tags: atomic-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

An atom meets one of its electrons in an excited state. The average time that
this remains in that state is $1 × 10^{−8}$ s to emit a photon of wavelength $620$ nm or $2$ eV energy.

My questions are: How does this uncertainty compare to the energy of the transition?
To what corresponds the variation in wavelength that it emits in average those atoms?

I already have the  uncertainty in the energy of that excited state, $$E≥h/t = 4.96\times 10^{-9} eV$$

Comment: The 2eV is the average energy of the transition, but it has a [natural linewidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_line#Line_broadening_and_shift) around it. [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution of the emitted photons in energy centers around the natural frequency/energy at 2eV, but extends around it by roughly *ΔE~ℏ/2τ*, so, then, ~33neV. ([Natural broadening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_line#Line_broadening_and_shift).)

You may easily convert this energy/frequency uncertainty to wavelength uncertainty.